# How to format PHP error_log lines, so it's readable?

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, timber

I'm working on a site that uses [Twig-templates via Timber](https://github.com/timber/timber) - and there is this "great" convention, that whenever something is wrong there, the entire `Timber::context` is written to the error log.

The code is written poorly, so waaaay to many things are added to that context.

That means, that whenever I hit an error or a warning, that I get this in the error log:

```
Timber\Timber::render($filenames = [0 => 'front-page.twig'], $data = ['http_host' => 'http://example.org', 'wp_title' => 'Home - Company Name', 'body_class' => 'home page-template page-template-front-page page-template-front-page-php page page-id-178 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support theme_black_bean', 'site' => class StarterSite { public $id = NULL; public $ID = NULL; public $object_type = NULL; public $admin_email = 'email@example.org'; public $blogname = NULL; public $charset = 'UTF-8'; public $description = ''; public $language = 'en_US'; public $multisite = FALSE; public $name = 'Company Name'; public $pingback_url = 'http://example.org/wp/xmlrpc.php'; public $siteurl = NULL; public $theme = class Timber\Theme { ... }; public $title = 'Company Name'; public $url = 'http://example.org'; public $home_url = 'http://example.org'; public $site_url = 'http://example.org/wp'; public $rdf = 'http://example.org/feed/rdf/'; public $rss = 'http://example.org/feed/rss/'; public $rss2 = 'http://example.org/feed/'; public $atom = 'http://example.org/feed/atom/'; public $pingback = 'http://example.org/wp/xmlrpc.php' }, 'request' => class Timber\Request { public $id = NULL; public $ID = NULL; public $object_type = NULL; public $post = [...]; public $get = [...] }, 'user' => class Timber\User { public $id = 409; public $ID = 409; public $object_type = 'user'; public $_link = NULL; public $avatar_override = NULL; public $description = ''; public $display_name = 'Company Name &amp; Co'; public $first_name = 'Company Name'; public $last_name = '&amp; Co'; public $user_nicename = 'pco_wp'; protected $roles = [...]; public $user_login = 'pco_wp'; public $user_email = 'my-email@company-name.dk'; public $user_url = ''; public $user_registered = '2023-01-20 10:04:26'; public $user_activation_key = ''; public $user_status = '0'; public $name = 'Company Name &amp; Co'; public $nickname = 'pco_wp'; public $rich_editing = 'true'; public $syntax_highlighting = 'true'; public $comment_shortcuts = 'false'; public $admin_color = 'fresh'; public $use_ssl = '0'; public $show_admin_bar_front = 'true'; public $locale = ''; public $wp_capabilities = [...]; public $wp_user_level = '10'; public $dismissed_wp_pointers = ''; public $_yoast_wpseo_profile_updated = '1674209066'; public $wpseo_ignore_tour = '1'; public $wp_dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id = '23417'; public $community-events-location = [...]; public $wp_ac_preferences_layout_table = [...]; public $activity = [...]; public $wp_persisted_preferences = [...]; public $session_tokens = [...] }, 'theme' => class Timber\Theme { public $id = NULL; public $ID = NULL; public $object_type = NULL; public $name = 'Company Name'; public $version = '1.0.0'; public $parent = FALSE; public $parent_slug = NULL; public $slug = 'company-name'; public $uri = 'http://example.org/wp-content/themes/company-name'; private $theme = class WP_Theme { ... } }, 'posts' => class Timber\PostQuery { public $found_posts = 1; protected $userQuery = FALSE; protected $queryIterator = class Timber\QueryIterator { ... }; protected $pagination = NULL; private ${ArrayObject}storage = [...] }, 'wp_head' => class Timber\FunctionWrapper { private $_class = NULL; private $_function = 'wp_head'; private $_args = [...]; private $_use_ob = FALSE }, 'wp_footer' => class Timber\FunctionWrapper { private $_class = NULL; private $_function = 'wp_footer'; private $_args = [...]; private $_use_ob = FALSE }, 'options' => ['visible_slides_quantity' => '10', 'image' => [...], 'podcast' => [...], 'slidedeck' => [...], 'video' => [...], 'search_posts_quantity' => [...], 'archive_posts_quantity' => [...], 'post' => [...], 'placeholder_image' => [...], 'share_popup_text' => '<p>Share content with anyone.</p>\n', 'google_api_key' => 'some-api-key', 'permissions_popup_text' => '<h4>Permissions for creative use of the resources from Company Name</h4>\n<p>Permission is granted to download images, slides and videos and use them in your own presentations, provided that copyright notices and the Company Name logo are not hidden or removed. For use in publications and on websites, proper attribution must be provided together with a link to <a class="css_builder--textBlue--1x8Cp css_builder--cursorPointer--GB0_1" href="http://example.org">Company Name.org</a></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n', 'about' => '<p>Company Name was founded by the Lundbeck Foundation <a href="https://lundbeckfonden.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">lundbeckfonden.com</a>.</p>\n', 'revisions_popup_text' => 'asdf asdf asfd asdf ', 'infinite_scroll_limit' => [...], 'not_found_page' => [...], 'tool' => [...], 'collection' => [...], 'details_popup_excerpt_length_words' => [...], 'pages' => [...], 'preloader_settings' => [...], 'user_activity_history_length' => '9', 'legal_description' => [...], 'show_hidden_features' => TRUE, 'tools_icons' => [...], 'feature_name' => 12947, 'profile_settings' => [...], 'global_text_variables' => [...], 'show_feature_name' => TRUE, 'show_slide_bundle' => TRUE, 'show_slide_lab' => TRUE, 'blank_slide_for_slidelab' => [...], 'trending_tags' => [...], 'shortcuts' => [...], 'ftp_slides' => [...]], 'placeholder' => class Timber\Image { public $id = 651; public $ID = 651; public $object_type = 'image'; public $ImageClass = 'Timber\\Image'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Timber\\Term'; public $custom = [...]; protected $___content = NULL; protected $_permalink = NULL; protected $_next = [...]; protected $_prev = [...]; protected $_css_class = NULL; public $post_author = '2'; public $post_content = ''; public $post_date = '2022-01-09 21:27:17'; public $post_excerpt = ''; public $post_parent = 0; public $post_status = 'inherit'; public $post_title = 'Placeholder New'; public $post_type = 'attachment'; public $slug = NULL; protected $__type = NULL; protected $_can_edit = NULL; protected $_dimensions = NULL; public $abs_url = NULL; private $file_types = [...]; public $file_loc = '/path/to/something/uploads/placeholder_new.jpg'; public $file = 'placeholder_new.jpg'; public $sizes = [...]; public $caption = ''; protected $_wp_attached_file = 'placeholder_new.jpg'; public $image_meta = [...]; public $wpmf_size = '54431'; public $wpmf_filetype = 'jpg'; public $wpmf_order = '0'; public $_wp_attachment_metadata = 'a:5:{s:5:"width";i:2000;s:6:"height";i:2000;s:4:"file";s:19:"placeholder_new.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:5:{s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"placeholder_new-300x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:5:"large";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:29:"placeholder_new-1024x1024.jpg";s:5:"width";i:1024;s:6:"height";i:1024;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:27:"placeholder_new-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";'...; public $post_date_gmt = '2022-01-09 21:27:17'; public $comment_status = 'open'; public $ping_status = 'closed'; public $post_password = ''; public $post_name = 'placeholder_new'; public $to_ping = ''; public $pinged = ''; public $post_modified = '2022-01-09 21:27:17'; public $post_modified_gmt = '2022-01-09 21:27:17'; public $post_content_filtered = ''; public $guid = 'http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/placeholder_new.jpg'; public $menu_order = 0; public $post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'; public $comment_count = '0'; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'stuff' => 'I am a value set in your functions.php file', 'topic_suggestions_menu' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 21; public $ID = 21; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'Theme suggestions'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 21; public $title = 'Theme suggestions'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'topic_suggestions'; public $slug = 'theme-suggestions'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 21; public $parent = 0; public $count = 6; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'more_suggestions_menu' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 22; public $ID = 22; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'More suggestions'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 22; public $title = 'More suggestions'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'more_suggestions'; public $slug = 'more-suggestions'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 22; public $parent = 0; public $count = 8; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'resources_menu' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 23; public $ID = 23; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'Resources'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 23; public $title = 'Resources'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'resources_menu'; public $slug = 'resources'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 23; public $parent = 0; public $count = 6; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'legal_pages' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 46; public $ID = 46; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'Footer menu'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 46; public $title = 'Footer menu'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'footer_menu'; public $slug = 'footer-menu'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 46; public $parent = 0; public $count = 5; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'footer_menu' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 46; public $ID = 46; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'Footer menu'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 46; public $title = 'Footer menu'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'footer_menu'; public $slug = 'footer-menu'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 46; public $parent = 0; public $count = 5; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'countries' => ['ID' => 0, 'key' => 'field_61f4619cc831c', 'label' => 'Country', 'name' => 'country', 'aria-label' => '', 'prefix' => 'acf', 'type' => 'select', 'value' => FALSE, 'menu_order' => 0, 'instructions' => '', 'required' => 0, 'id' => '', 'class' => '', 'conditional_logic' => 0, 'parent' => 'group_61f46193756f7', 'wrapper' => [...], 'choices' => [...], 'default_value' => FALSE, 'allow_null' => 0, 'multiple' => 0, 'ui' => 0, 'return_format' => 'array', 'ajax' => 0, 'placeholder' => '', '_name' => 'country', '_valid' => 1], 'professions' => ['ID' => 0, 'key' => 'field_61f461bfc831d', 'label' => 'Profession', 'name' => 'profession', 'aria-label' => '', 'prefix' => 'acf', 'type' => 'select', 'value' => FALSE, 'menu_order' => 1, 'instructions' => '', 'required' => 0, 'id' => '', 'class' => '', 'conditional_logic' => 0, 'parent' => 'group_61f46193756f7', 'wrapper' => [...], 'choices' => [...], 'default_value' => FALSE, 'allow_null' => 0, 'multiple' => 0, 'ui' => 0, 'return_format' => 'array', 'ajax' => 0, 'placeholder' => '', '_name' => 'profession', '_valid' => 1], 'main_navigation_menu' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 44; public $ID = 44; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'Main Menu'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 44; public $title = 'Main Menu'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'main_navigation'; public $slug = 'main-menu'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 44; public $parent = 0; public $count = 5; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'resources_navigation_menu' => class Timber\Menu { public $id = 45; public $ID = 45; public $object_type = 'term'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Term'; public $_children = NULL; public $name = 'Resources navigation menu'; public $taxonomy = 'nav_menu'; public $MenuItemClass = 'Timber\\MenuItem'; public $depth = 0; public $items = [...]; public $term_id = 45; public $title = 'Resources navigation menu'; public $options = [...]; public $raw_options = [...]; public $theme_location = 'resources_navigation'; public $slug = 'resources-navigation-menu'; public $term_group = 0; public $term_taxonomy_id = 45; public $parent = 0; public $count = 6; public $filter = 'raw' }, 'breadcrumbs' => '', 'current_url' => 'http://example.org/', 'Feature Names' => [], 'post' => class Timber\Post { public $id = 178; public $ID = 178; public $object_type = 'post'; public $ImageClass = 'Timber\\Image'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Timber\\Term'; public $custom = [...]; protected $___content = NULL; protected $_permalink = NULL; protected $_next = [...]; protected $_prev = [...]; protected $_css_class = NULL; public $post_author = '2'; public $post_content = ''; public $post_date = '2022-01-02 20:02:19'; public $post_excerpt = ''; public $post_parent = 0; public $post_status = 'publish'; public $post_title = 'Home'; public $post_type = 'page'; public $slug = 'home'; protected $__type = NULL; public $_edit_lock = '1671109567:172'; public $_edit_last = '240'; public $_yoast_wpseo_estimated-reading-time-minutes = '0'; public $_wp_page_template = 'front-page.php'; public $hero_slide = [...]; public $_hero_slide = 'field_61d2ca8d799c9'; public $account_features_0_title = 'Slide Decks'; public $_account_features_0_title = 'field_61d2cbf9fc19d'; public $account_features_0_content = 'Odasdfasdf asdf asdf asdf '; public $_account_features_0_content = 'field_61d2cc1ffc19e'; public $account_features_0_link = [...]; public $_account_features_0_link = 'field_61d2cc35fc19f'; public $account_features_0_image = '13349'; public $_account_features_0_image = 'field_61d2cc54fc1a0'; public $account_features_0_image_position = '0'; public $_account_features_0_image_position = 'field_61d2d276121f3'; public $account_features_1_title = 'Collections'; public $_account_features_1_title = 'field_61d2cbf9fc19d'; public $account_features_1_content = 'asdf asdf asfd asdf asdf dasdf '; public $_account_features_1_content = 'field_61d2cc1ffc19e'; public $account_features_1_link = [...]; public $_account_features_1_link = 'field_61d2cc35fc19f'; public $account_features_1_image = '17265'; public $_account_features_1_image = 'field_61d2cc54fc1a0'; public $account_features_1_image_position = '0'; public $_account_features_1_image_position = 'field_61d2d276121f3'; public $account_features_2_title = 'Feature Name'; public $_account_features_2_title = 'field_61d2cbf9fc19d'; public $account_features_2_content = 'Create a profile for free and use your personal Feature Name to save content and material you would like to return to, work with, or share with others. It\'s available to all and without cost.'; public $_account_features_2_content = 'field_61d2cc1ffc19e'; public $account_features_2_link = [...]; public $_account_features_2_link = 'field_61d2cc35fc19f'; public $account_features_2_image = '18101'; public $_account_features_2_image = 'field_61d2cc54fc1a0'; public $account_features_2_image_position = '1'; public $_account_features_2_image_position = 'field_61d2d276121f3'; public $account_features = '3'; public $_account_features = 'field_61d2cbc6fc19c'; public $themes_title = 'Themes'; public $_themes_title = 'field_61d3315fdc95b'; public $themes_description = 'Comprehensive selection of content, organized by themes within psychiatry, neurology and neuroscience. You can find slide decks, articles, images and other content within each theme.'; public $_themes_description = 'field_61d3316adc95c'; public $themes_category = [...]; public $_themes_category = 'field_61d33179dc95d'; public $themes = ''; public $_themes = 'field_61d33142dc95a'; public $estimate_required_time = ''; public $color_scheme = 'theme_black_bean'; public $_color_scheme = 'field_61d46ae5cedf5'; public $contributers = ''; public $_contributers = 'field_61de11d90d221'; public $feature_name_title = 'asdf asf asdf asdf asdf a'; public $_feature_name_title = 'field_620fc401ad799'; public $feature_name_description = 'asdfasdf asdf asf asdf '; public $_feature_name_description = 'field_620fc401ad79a'; public $feature_name_button_text = 'Explore Feature Name'; public $_feature_name_button_text = 'field_620fc401ad79b'; public $feature_name_image = '12952'; public $_feature_name_image = 'field_620fc4e9ad79c'; public $feature_name = ''; public $_feature_name = 'field_620fc401ad798'; public $hero_slide_interval_seconds = '10'; public $_hero_slide_interval_seconds = 'field_621f5816f6197'; public $hefo_before = '0'; public $hefo_after = '0'; public $relevant_content_title = 'Learn more...'; public $_relevant_content_title = 'field_63335ca2f8b4a'; public $relevant_content_order = [...]; public $_relevant_content_order = 'field_6359a3ebe9aa1'; public $relevant_content = ''; public $_relevant_content = 'field_63335c89f8b49'; public $post_date_gmt = '2022-01-02 20:02:19'; public $comment_status = 'closed'; public $ping_status = 'closed'; public $post_password = ''; public $post_name = 'home'; public $to_ping = ''; public $pinged = ''; public $post_modified = '2022-11-28 15:58:20'; public $post_modified_gmt = '2022-11-28 14:58:20'; public $post_content_filtered = ''; public $guid = 'http://neurotoriom.com/?page_id=178'; public $menu_order = 0; public $post_mime_type = ''; public $comment_count = '0'; public $filter = 'raw'; public $status = 'publish' }, 'feature_name' => class Timber\Post { public $id = 12947; public $ID = 12947; public $object_type = 'post'; public $ImageClass = 'Timber\\Image'; public $PostClass = 'Timber\\Post'; public $TermClass = 'Timber\\Term'; public $custom = [...]; protected $___content = NULL; protected $_permalink = NULL; protected $_next = [...]; protected $_prev = [...]; protected $_css_class = NULL; public $post_author = '231'; public $post_content = '<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>Explore relevant areas of the feature with the  Feature Name</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->'; public $post_date = '2022-03-01 16:04:56'; public $post_excerpt = ''; public $post_parent = 0; public $post_status = 'publish'; public $post_title = ' Feature Name'; public $post_type = 'tool'; public $slug = 'feature-name'; protected $__type = NULL; public $estimate_required_time = ''; public $_edit_lock = '1669279132:231'; public $_edit_last = '231'; public $permissions = ''; public $_permissions = 'field_61df2eb1d9ba6'; public $tool_type = 'feature_name'; public $_tool_type = 'field_620e49d99709b'; public $references = ''; public $_references = 'field_61d8613cf295a'; public $reviews = ''; public $_reviews = 'field_61dfe0a8b59ce'; public $_yoast_wpseo_estimated-reading-time-minutes = '1'; public $_wp_old_slug = 'explore-relevant-areas-of-the-feature-with-the--feature-name'; public $_thumbnail_id = '19915'; public $_yoast_wpseo_content_score = '90'; public $Feature Names = [...]; public $_Feature Names = 'field_61fd03b60484e'; public $tags_custom = ''; public $_tags_custom = 'field_62865191007dc'; public $relevant = '0'; public $_relevant = 'field_61d1ab928f3bf'; public $_yoast_wpseo_is_cornerstone = '1'; public $post_date_gmt = '2022-03-01 15:04:56'; public $comment_status = 'closed'; public $ping_status = 'closed'; public $post_password = ''; public $post_name = 'feature-name'; public $to_ping = ''; public $pinged = ''; public $post_modified = '2022-11-24 09:38:51'; public $post_modified_gmt = '2022-11-24 08:38:51'; public $post_content_filtered = ''; public $guid = 'https://another-domain.org/?post_type=tool&#038;p=12947'; public $menu_order = 0; public $post_mime_type = ''; public $comment_count = '0'; public $filter = 'raw'; public $status = 'publish' }, 'latest' => [0 => class Timber\Post { ... }, 1 => class Timber\Post { ... }, 2 => class Timber\Post { ... }], 'relevant' => [0 => class Timber\Post { ... }, 1 => class Timber\Post { ... }, 2 => class Timber\Post { ... }, 3 => class Timber\Post { ... }, 4 => class Timber\Post { ... }], 'relevant_tags' => [25 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 34 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 36 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 125 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 92 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 133 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 104 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 99 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 49 => class Timber\Term { ... }], 'relevant_categories' => [7 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 132 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 124 => class Timber\Term { ... }, 1 => class Timber\Term { ... }]], $expires = *uninitialized*, $cache_mode = *uninitialized*) /path/to/something/company-name/front-page.php:49
```

### Overarching question

How do I format that, so it's easily readable?

Something like this:

```
Timber\Timber::render(
  $filenames = [
    0 => 'front-page.twig'
  ], 
  $data = [
    'http_host' => 'http://example.org', 
    'wp_title' => 'Home - Company Name', 
    'body_class' => 'home page-template page-template-front-page page-template-front-page-php page page-id-178 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support theme_black_bean',
    'site' => class StarterSite { 
      public $id = NULL; 
      public $ID = NULL; 
      public $object_type = NULL; 
      public $admin_email = 'email@example.org'; 
      public $blogname = NULL; 
      public $charset = 'UTF-8'; 
      public $description = ''; 
      public $language = 'en_US'; 
      public $multisite = FALSE; 
      public $theme = class Timber\Theme { ... };
  ...
...
```

Ideally, it would be formattet nicely *inside* the error-log, but that requires changes to the 3rd party plugin from Timber.

### Solution consideration 1: ChatGPT

Try to pour it into ChatGPT and tell it to format it nicely.
ChatGPT was down. And it also seems like an unreliable solution.

### Solution consideration 2: Add it to file

I thought that I could potentially add it to a new file and then make a little program, to open that file and format it. But that's also excessive.

But since it's `print_r`ed text, then it's not really PHP and not really anything else.

### Solution consideration 3: Graylog

I get the error locally (in a Docker-setup), so I attempt to spin up a Graylog container, that should catch these errors, hoping that Graylog would format it a bit.

### Solution consideration 4: A piece of software or a website

I looked for at piece of software and/or a website that could do it for me, but I can't find it.

Comment: Example of log output? Context is normally serialized using `json_encode` or `serialize` and log lines are one line.
Also there are a ton of tools available to format log output...

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, @CodeSpirit . Can you mention some of these tools you mention?

Comment: [JetBrains/logviewer](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideolog) when youre using jetbrains products or [VSCode Log File Highlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emilast.LogFileHighlighter)